# Компилируется C++ tcp client, но не отправляет данные. Почему?

Tags: c++, windows, сокет

Компилируется в exe, все запускается, но не отправляет "O" серверу. Почему?

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>

#define WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable:4996) 

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    cout << "Klient running";

    char mes[30] = "O";

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    struct sockaddr_in serv;

    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_port = htons(5050);
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    int j = connect(s, (struct sockaddr*) & serv, NULL);

    int h = send(s, mes, NULL, NULL);

    Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: потому что длина сообщения — '0'... смотри какие аргументы принимает `send()`

Comment: А как указать длину?

Comment: Почему вы не вызываете [`WSAStartup`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup). Почему не проверяете возвращаемые значения?

Comment: Оказывается send() принимает третьим аргументом int len, указал, но не работает. А как WSAStartup вызывать. Сорри за глупые вопросы, но я чайник, прост некоторую часть проекта нужно сделать на C++

Comment: @ヒミコ, ^ ... 2 tilekvj, упоминай ник через собаку, если ждёшь дальнейших  ответов в комментариях... по поводу `WSAStartup` — это особенность winapi, по деталям яхз, так что смотри доки или подожди кого-нить, кто знает...

Comment: вот так https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup